# Polymer. Paper-submenu trigger works on two elements inside paper-item

Tags: javascript, html, angular, polymer

I need some help in Polymer's paper-menu/submenu. I have task to make navigation panel with tree structure that is based on paper-menu. So, I have problem with "menu-trigger" class inside paper-item tag, I have two elements inside paper-item:icon and link with two different events clicking on them. When I click on icon  it collapses another paper-menu, when click on link it doing another event, but now both of them collapses another menu. How can I separate this events?

PS: sorry for my English:)

```
  <paper-menu>
    <paper-submenu>
      <!--Problem starts here-->
      <paper-item class="menu-trigger">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE2C7;</i>
        <a (click)="someAction()">Test 1</a>
      </paper-item>
      <!--And finishs here-->
      <paper-menu class="menu-content sublist">
        <paper-submenu>
          <paper-item class="menu-trigger">
            <i class="material-icons ">&#xE313;</i>
            <a>Test 1.1</a>
          </paper-item>
          <paper-menu class="menu-content sublist2">
            <paper-item>
              <a>Test 1.1.1</a>
            </paper-item>
            <paper-item>
              <a>Test 1.1.2</a>
            </paper-item>
          </paper-menu>
        </paper-submenu>
        <paper-item>
           <a>Test 1.2</a>
        </paper-item>
        <paper-item>
           <a>Test 1.3</a>
        </paper-item>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-submenu>
  </paper-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use some `on-tap` or `on-click` events and some js to show/hide the submenus.

Answer (score 0):

So,if someone interested in some solutions for this problem: I used `pointer-events: none;` in css, but I think it was not best idea, so that is why i decided to use `event.stopPropagation();`.

Answer (score 0):

On click of paper-menu/sub-menu there are few events that trigger.

`iron-activate`: (selected or deselected)

`iron-deselect`: deselected

`iron-items-changed`: select items change

`iron-select`: select event

these events has two **params** (**event**, **selecteditem**)
based on your requirement take **selecteditem** and apply your logic

more info: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-menu